# jQuery not working in ASP.Net webforms

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery is not working at all (ASP.Net webforms using masterpages).

The following script doesn't even put up the alert box (It is in the .aspx page in the main content section)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("working");
    });​
</script>
```

My master pages source jquery from google api, coded like this;

```
<link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Styles/nav.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<link href="Content/jquery.lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery.lightbox.min.js" ></script>
```

any help would be appreciated. I've had scripts working on this site before but now that script won't run, even on other pages.

Comment: any errors? are you running the script after including jQuery?

Comment: im getting an error that jquery 1.8.1.js is not found, but im using google api via CDN and its looking in my scripts folder. Its looking for modernizr there too and that file is there, right version number and all

Comment: http://localhost:49767/EnerTeckWebsite_December2012/(S(mopkqwk152r3szanse1ywmi0))/EmployeeArea/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js  its looking for modenizr there but its in root/Scripts folder not EmployeeArea/Scripts folder, which there isnt one

Comment: well maybe because your jquery link seems to be broken? Try add a http to the front of it

Answer (score 0):

Add http in src of Google address of jquery you added.